# Internally, In a cluster of hadoop and hive installed, what is happening?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a 4 node cluster and i have Hive installed in all the nodes,(1 name node and 3 data nodes).

I am accessing the name node. What happens when i want to put a file. Internally what is happening between name nodes and data nodes?

Similarly, What happens when i want to put a file via the data node?

And the table we create in Hive where is it getting stored?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise taking a look at [this excellent comic on how HDFS works](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-zw6KHOtbT4MmRkZWJjYzEtYjI3Ni00NTFjLWE0OGItYTU5OGMxYjc0N2M1/edit). To sumarize what happens:

- The client knows the block size (default 64Mb), so it starts by splitting your file into blocks defined by this block size.
- Then for each block it will send a query to the NameNode to ask to which datanodes it can write this block and how many datanodes it wants to write to (replication factor).
- The Namenode replies with a list of datanode addresses sorted by increasing distance from the client.
- The client sends the block data to the closest datanode, along with the addresses of the other datanodes.
- The first datanode will also stream the incoming data to the closest datanode that is in the list provided the client, and also pass the list to this second datanode.
- The second datanode does the same thing and will also stream the data to another datanode if needed.
- When all the data has been written to the datanodes for a given block of your input file, they will all inform the Namenode that they have finished storing this block.
- When the datanodes are done, the client will ask to do the same for the other blocks of your input file.
- When all blocks have been stored like this, the client will tell the Namenode it's done so that the Namenode can persist the metadata about this file to disk.

A bit complex but that's what the protocol looks like.

When you create a table in Hive, the metadata about this table (columns, SerDe, location, ...) goes into the Hive Metastore which is the central repository of all your Hive tables. There are several backends for this metastore and the most common ones are Derby or MySQL, and this is controlled via the properties `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL` and `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName` in your Hive configs. Ultimately the data ends up in HDFS in a directory controlled by `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` which defaults to `/user/hive/warehouse`.

Comment: So, this is my understanding. please correct me if I'm wrong.
 when i put a file via the name node it get stored in the data node. and the data which we load into the Hive table, is stored in the data node and the metadata is stored in the metastore.

Comment: Can u please explain what will happen if i try to put a file or create a table via the data node? will it first talk to the name node and do the processing or will directly store the data into data node?

Comment: Yes you are correct, you should look at data in HDFS just as a sequence of blocks whose physical location is in the datanodes.

Comment: thank you. how about when i try to put a file via a data node? what happens then?

Comment: Hi Charles, I happen to read something about Hive's warehouse directory. Can u please explain were this Hive warehouse is? is it in the namenode or datanode?